# Nodejs middleware .pre shows not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
    var categoryList = new Referral({categoryList : category});

    categoryList.pre('save', function (next) {
        Referral.find({categoryList : category}, function (err, docs) {
            if (!docs.length){
                next();
            }else{
                console.log('Data exists: ', category);
                next(new Error("Data exists!"));
            }
        })
    })
```

Referral is my variable assigned to my schema.
categoryList is the object

This gives an error

> TypeError: categoryList.pre is not a function    at
>   D:\Aventyn\ClipCare_v2\app\api.js:112:18    at Layer.handle [as
>   handle_request]
>   (D:\Aventyn\ClipCare_v2\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>   at next
>   (D:\Aventyn\ClipCare_v2\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
>   at Route.dispatch
>   (D:\Aventyn\ClipCare_v2\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>   at Layer.handle [as handle_request]
>   (D:\Aventyn\ClipCare_v2\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>   at
>   D:\Aventyn\ClipCare_v2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
>   at Function.process_params
>   (D:\Aventyn\ClipCare_v2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
>   at next
>   (D:\Aventyn\ClipCare_v2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
>   at Function.handle
>   (D:\Aventyn\ClipCare_v2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:176:3)
>   at router
>   (D:\Aventyn\ClipCare_v2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:46:12)
>   at Layer.handle [as handle_request]
>   (D:\Aventyn\ClipCare_v2\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>   at trim_prefix
>   (D:\Aventyn\ClipCare_v2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
>   at
>   D:\Aventyn\ClipCare_v2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7 
>   at Function.process_params
>   (D:\Aventyn\ClipCare_v2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
>   at next
>   (D:\Aventyn\ClipCare_v2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
>   at
>   D:\Aventyn\ClipCare_v2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:618:15

Answer (score 5):

Try changing:

```
categoryList.pre('save', function (next) {
  // ...
})
```

to:

```
categoryList.schema.pre('save', function (next) {
  // ...
})
```

The `.pre()` is a method of the Mongoose schema, not a model.

Comment: When I use the categoryList.schema.pre('save', function (next) {
  // ...
})   It just keeps loading and it does not show any error in the server console.

Answer (score 0):

Middleware (like `pre` hooks) are part of a schema. It looks like you're trying to use it on a single document, which is not how it works.

Instead, use it on the schema that you used to create the `Referral` model:

```
ReferralSchema.pre('save', ...);
```

This does mean that the pre hook will be applied to *all* documents of that schema.

Comment: While posting data from AngularJS to mongodb using mongoose, can **.pre**  be used to check duplicates in mongodb?

Comment: @Vignesh not reliably, no. You should probably use [unique (sparse) indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/) to enfore uniqueness on particular fields.